# Avoid PySide6 dark theme

Tags: pyside6, ubuntu-22.04

I am migrating a program from PySide2 to PySide6.

To my horror, PySide6 colours the app the same colour as the OS theme by default.

For instance, under Ubuntu 22.04, I've chosen the dark theme which looks ok for most apps. However these particular Apps I am migrating look much better with the clear theme, but PySide6 colours them with the dark theme without me telling them to do so.

**How can I force PySide6 to use the default theme (the clear one) ?**

Comment: Unfortunately, it probably just follows the system palette, so it depends on what the OS provides. Unless I'm wrong, it's not (yet) possible to automatically get/force the "light mode", as that is a read only property of QStyleHint. What you could eventually do is to *copy* the palette when using light mode, and then hard code it in your program.

Answer (score 1):

The default theming when migrating to PySide6 is terrible and the style will break. However I've found a workaround; Using [pyqtdarktheme](https://github.com/5yutan5/PyQtDarkTheme)

It allows to have both dark and light themes and looks very nice.

Comment: Note that you could even create your own palette using reference colors: see the generic [`QPalette(color)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpalette.html#QPalette-1) and [`QPalette(buttonColor, windowColor)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpalette.html#QPalette-3) constructors. And, obviously, you can create your *full* palette, which is just a matter of 9 basic color roles, and is certainly better than using a *whole* different style (since you're using it for the "wrong" reason).

Comment: Indeed I'm using it for the wrong reason, but the styling is far better than the stock one with close to no effort. Anyway, this should be an issue for the PySide6 team...